# Choose which mysql table to update in php post

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I have a form handler (I believe that is the correct terminology) called `insert.php`, this is used to post form data to a MySQL database on localhost.  I have different tables each containing a single record and would like to choose which table the data goes to.  I could duplicate the insert.php file for each table but that seems messy.  How do I  choose which table the data goes to via post?

current insert.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$con=mysqli_connect($hh,$un,$pw,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$sql = "UPDATE PiBQ_Temp SET reqdTemp = '$_POST[setTemp]' WHERE tempKey = 1";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "1 record added";
header ('location: index.php');

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

What I think is needed for the `$sql =` variable:

```
$sql = "UPDATE '$_POST[myTable]' SET '$_POST[myField]' = '$_POST[myValue]' WHERE tableKey = 1"
```

My html is this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="myField" value="<?= $myValue ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

what html should I be using to feed my revised `insert.php` file above, if that is correct?  Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on sql injection. Note that using a prepared statement will only help `$_POST[myValue]`. Table- and column names you would have to check against whitelists.

Comment: To make this work, add to your form: `<input type="hidden" name="myTable" value="<?= $myTable ?>"/>`

Comment: you're also mixing different mysql apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this format

```
$sql = "UPDATE `".$_POST['myTable']."` SET `".$_POST['myField']."` = '".$_POST['myValue']."' WHERE `tableKey` = 1";
```

or

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `".$mysqli->real_escape_string(str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($_POST['myTable'])))."` SET `".$mysqli->real_escape_string(str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($_POST['myField'])))."` = ? WHERE `tableKey` = 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['myValue']);
$stmt->execute();
```

- You should use prepared statement instead

Comment: This query has the same security issues as the original.

Comment: You can't bind table or field name to prepared statement.

Comment: What would the html be for the submit code to make use of your revised `$sql =` statement?

Answer (score 0):

There's some wider practices that could be improve, but **based on your current code/structure**, I would use something like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';


try {
    $con = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".$e;
}


$table = (isset($_POST['myTable'])) ? $_POST['myTable'] : null;

$reqdTemp = (isset($_POST['setTemp'])) ? $_POST['setTemp'] : null;
$tempKey  = (isset($_POST['setKey'])) ? $_POST['setKey'] : null;

switch($table) {
    case "thisTable":
        $qry = "UPDATE `thisTable` SET thisField = ? WHERE thisKey = ?";
        break;
    case "thatTable":
        $qry = "UPDATE `thatTable` SET thisField = ? WHERE thisKey = ?";
        break;
    case "anotherTable":
        $qry = "UPDATE `anotherTable` SET thisField = ? WHERE thisKey = ?";
        break;
    default:
        // do something?
        break;
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $reqdTemp, $tempKey);
$stmt->execute();

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
echo $stmt->error;
}
else {
echo "1 record added";
}

header ('location: index.php');

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Two things to note:  The switch statement allows you to provide a different query based on the table name, but it assumes that the same structure is in place (i.e. `update String Where Integer`).

I've also assumed the `thisKey` is posted too, as 'setKey'.

Secondly, prepared statements.

This is more of a hint, rather than a whole solution, and you probably need to tidy it up and make it work for you outside of my assumptions